# Communication between Pods in Kubernetes. Service object or Cluster Networking?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod, azure-aks

I'm a beginner in Kubernetes and I have a situation as following: I have two differents Pods: **PodA** and **PodB**. Firstly, I want to expose **PodA** to the outside world, so I create a **Service** (type NodePort or LoadBalancer) for **PodA**, which is not difficult to understand for me.

Then I want **PodA** communicate to **PodB**, and after several hours googling, I found the answer is that I also need to create a **Service** (type ClusterIP if I want to keep **PodB** *only visible* inside the cluster) for **PodB**, and if I do so, I can let **PodA** and **PodB** comminucate to each other. But the problem is I also found [this article](https://matthewpalmer.net/kubernetes-app-developer/articles/kubernetes-networking-guide-beginners.html). According to this webpage, they say that [*the communication between pods on the same node*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PdHj.gif) can be done via `cbr0`, a **Network Bridge**, or [*the communication between pods on different nodes*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEkB6.gif) can be done via a `route table` of the cluster, and they don't mention anything to the **Service** object (which means we don't need **Service** object ???).

In fact, I also read the documents of K8s and I found in the [Cluster Networking](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/)

> **Cluster Networking**
>   ...
>  
>   2. Pod-to-Pod communications: this is the primary focus of this document.
>   ...

where they also focus on to the **Pod-to-Pod communications**, but there is no stuff relevant to the **Service** object.

So, I'm really confusing right now and my question is: Could you please explain to me the connection between these stuff in [the article](https://matthewpalmer.net/kubernetes-app-developer/articles/kubernetes-networking-guide-beginners.html) and the **Service** object? The **Service** object is a high-level abstract of the `cbr0` and `route table`? And in the end, how can the **Pods** can communicate to each other?

If I misunderstand something, please, point it out for me, I really appreciate that.

Thank you guys !!!

Comment: if your podA needs to connect to the podB through a ClusterIP, the application doesn't need to know nothing about the cni used by the cluster.

Answer (score 3):

Motivation behind using a service in a Kubernetes cluster.

Kubernetes Pods are mortal. They are born and when they die, they are not resurrected. If you use a Deployment to run your app, it can create and destroy Pods dynamically.

Each Pod gets its own IP address, however in a Deployment, the set of Pods running in one moment in time could be different from the set of Pods running that application a moment later.

This leads to a problem: if some set of Pods (call them “backends”) provides functionality to other Pods (call them “frontends”) inside your cluster, how do the frontends find out and keep track of which IP address to connect to, so that the frontend can use the backend part of the workload?

That being said, a service is handy when your deployments (podA and podB) are dynamically managed.

Answer (score 2):

Your PodA can always communicate with PodB *if* it knows the address or the DNS name of PodB. In a cluster environment, there may be multiple replicas of PodB, or an instance of PodB may die and be replaced by another instance with a different address and different name. A `Service` is an abstraction to deal with this situation. If you use a `Service` to expose your PodB, then all pods in the cluster can talk to an instance of PodB using that service, which has a fixed name and fixed address no matter how many instances of PodB exists and what their addresses are.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so my understand is the `cbr0` or `route table` that I mentionned in my question are the low-level in K8s, whereas the `Service` is a high-level that we, the programmers, can use to deal with the problem? Am I right, please? I'm sorry if I say something stupid but I just want to know if there is a relevance between these stuff or not.

Comment: That is correct. k8s manages the routing table on the nodes to implement the high-level networking you should be using. The bridges, routing tables, etc. are the components of the underlying network. K8s implements a software-defined network using those primitives. As I said, you can reach pods directly without a service because the network is configured to support that, but service gives you a fixed name and address regardless of the location and name of the target pod.

Answer (score 0):

First, I read it as you are dealing with two *applications*, e.g. `ApplicationA` and `ApplicationB`. Don't use the *Pod* abstraction when you reason about your architecture. On Kubernetes, you are dealing with a *distributed system*, and it is designed so that you should have *multiple instances* of your Application, e.g. for High Availability. Each instance of your application is a `Pod`.

Deploy your applications `ApplicationA` and `ApplicationB` as a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) resource. Then it is easy do do rolling upgrades without downtime, and Kubernetes will restart any instance of your application if it crash.

For every `Deployment` or for you, *application*, create one `Service` resource, (e.g. `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`). When you communicate from `ApplicationA` to another *application*, use the Service, e.g. `ServiceB`. The service will *load balance* your requests to the instances of the other application, and you can upgrade your `Deployment` without downtime.

Answer (score 0):

1.Cluster networking : As the name suggests, all the pods deployed in the cluster will be connected by implementing any kubernetes network model like DANM, flannel
Check this link to see how to create a cluster network.
[Creating cluster network](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network)

With the CNI installed (by implementing cluster network), every pod will get an IP.

2.Service objects created with type ClusterIP, points to the this IPs (via endpoint) created internally to communicate.

Answering your question, Yes, The Service object is a high-level abstract of the cbr0 and route table.

You can use service object to communicate between pods.
You can also implement service mesh like envoy / Istio if the network is complex.